# Changing background of UITableViewCells in Edit Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have trouble with a black table view appearing white when swiping left to delete (in my case void) a row.

I tried setting every possible parameter for color in every step all the way from the ViewController down to the Content of the TableViewCell.

I managed to get it darkGray for "selection" with the following in CellForRowAtIndex:

```
 UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

So I figure the solution is something like that.

I have a similar setup on iPhone where the TableView is in a TableViewController where the issue does not occur. In this particular situation the TableView is in a regular ViewController.

Screenshots attached. Please advise. Edit: Note that the white space is not a button that appears next to the Void-button. It's white space that changes size according to how far your drag the cell. If you release the cell the white space disappears entirely, but the bounce reveals the white space.

Swiped left (in motion):

[image]

Swiped left (released):

[image]

Unswiped:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a complete screen shot of your cell with & without delete option appearing. Also post your code part too for looking into it for issue.

Comment: What code part do you want? There is no code involved in the actual swiping other than allowing it with CanEditRowForIndex, which just returns true for my table. Added another screenshot unswiped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow - it turns out I only needed to implement the following method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
```

Ironically I searched high and low for a solution, only to find it 15 minutes after I ask. It's been bugging me for weeks.

Ah, well, maybe someone else stumbles across this problem.